# SimplePostTool: FATAL: Connection error in Solr when trying to index

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

I am new to Solr and when I was indexing xml document in my solr, then I got this error.

```
C:\apache-solr-3.2.0\example\exampledocs>java -jar post.jar *.xml
SimplePostTool: version 1.3
SimplePostTool: POSTing files to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: POSTing file gb18030-example.xml
SimplePostTool: FATAL: IOException while posting data: java.net.ConnectException
: Connection refused: connect
```

then I realized that my port number in my case is 7788 for localhost so I did this:-

```
java -Durl=localhost:7788/solr/update -jar post.jar solr.xml
```

then I am getting this error

```
C:\apache-solr-3.2.0\example\exampledocs>java -Durl=localhost:7788/solr/update -
jar post.jar *.xml
SimplePostTool: version 1.3
SimplePostTool: FATAL: System Property 'url' is not a valid URL: null
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that -Durl is understood by the post.jar (hope it is) but if that parameter is honoured, then it should probably be used like this:

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:7788/solr/update -jar post.jar solr.xml
```

ah, just found this reference, which suggests that the parameter is honoured:
<strike>http://borort.wordpress.com/2008/11/19/solr-postjar-post-to-deferent-solr-port-other-than-8983/</strike>

Answer (score 3):

For me, this was happening because I failed to start Solr (running in the background) while attempting to load the data... DUH!

Answer (score 2):

just check that your solr server is up or not ..

if is is not running then run the solr server ..

and in the other

`cmd run this C:\apache-solr-3.2.0\example\exampledocs>java -jar post.jar *.xml`

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek, this is a common mistake we used to make while running solr in dev mode. Thank you for pointing out!